# Joining view and tables in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have the following tables.

**Customer** `Customer_id, Customer_name`

**Customer_details**  `Customer_id,Phone_no,Address`

**Order_details** `Order_id,Customer_id,Order_type`

I have created a view as following

```
  Create  view Orders_Analysis
  Select c.Customer_id,cd.phone_no,od.order_id
  From customer c
       inner join order_details od
          on c. Customer_id=od. Customer_id
       Inner join Where c. Customer_id=cd. Customer_id
          cd. Customer_id=c.Customer_id
```

Now using the above view and pre mentioned tables I have to extract only those records in the view which are of a particular order_type.

Can you guys suggest me a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You have some mistake in View, This is the correct View after fix mistakes

```
Create view Orders_Analysis
  Select c.Customer_id,cd.phone_no,od.order_id
  From customer c
     INNER JOIN order_details od
        ON c.Customer_id = od.Customer_id
     INNER JOIN Customer_details CD 
        ON c.Customer_id = cd.Customer_id
```

Now You want to extract only those records in the view which are of a particular order_type.

**Solution One:-** Because you dont have column order_type in View then use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT * 
 FROM Orders_Analysis OA
      INNER JOIN Order_details OD
        ON OA.order_id = OD.order_id
 WHERE OD.Order_type = your value here
```

**Solution Two:-**

Otherwise Add Order-Type column in View

```
Create view Orders_Analysis
      Select c.Customer_id,cd.phone_no,od.order_id,od.order_type
      From customer c
         INNER JOIN order_details od
            ON c.Customer_id = od.Customer_id
         INNER JOIN Customer_details CD 
            ON c.Customer_id = cd.Customer_id
```

and use

```
Select * from Orders_Analysis where Order_Type =  your value here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the field, od.order_type, to the Select statement results set in your view definition:

```
SELECT c.Customer_id,cd.phone_no,od.order_id,od.Order_type
```

Then, if you run a select against the view, specify a WHERE clause on the order_type field for the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Update your view and select also order type

```
Select c.Customer_id,cd.phone_no,od.order_id, od.Order_type
```

You can now execute select query using the view you created

```
Select * from Orders_Analysis where Order_Type = "any value"
```